# What is the correct way of creating a view in Postgres with two joined tables?

Tags: python, postgresql, join

I have two tables.

DDL:

```
A: a_id, b_id, a_name
B: b_id, b_name
```

Data:

```
A:{1, 1, "apple"}, {2, 2, "cherry"}, {3,1,"lemon"}
B:{1, "yellow"}, {2, "black"}
```

I would like to create a view where the data is like this:

```
1, "apple, "yellow"
2, "cherry, "black"
3, "lemon, "yellow"
```

I am trying to create the view with the following:

```
CREATE VIEW a_full AS
  SELECT *
    FROM a, b
    WHERE  a.b_id = b.b_id;
```

It gives me the following error:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "b_id" specified more than once

Table A is way bigger than table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because b_id is common name in A and B table, you have to use prefix `tablename`:

```
CREATE VIEW a_full AS
  SELECT a.a_id, a.b_id, a.a_name,b. b_name 
    FROM a, b
    WHERE  a.b_id = b.b_id;
```

Comment: Great, what happens if I would like to include in the results b.b_id? I get:ERROR:  column "b_id" specified more than once.

Comment: isn't a.b_id=b.b_id? so why do you need them both?, you can alias it: `b.b_id as bb_id`

Answer (score 1):

You could retain the wildcard if you use the `using` clause in an join:

```
create or replace view a_full as
select *
from a
join b using (b_id)
```